# I could't change all of filenames in a folder and remove specific character using python

Tags: python

I coded how to load and save txt file using pandas in python.

I want remove 'abc:,'data in all test(1,2,3,4,5).csv files, but I don't know how to delete and replace data.

Do you know how to rename(change) file name and remove data (specific character) in python?

Answer (score 1):

Lets use `pathlib` and `pandas` to ease your current solution.

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import re

p = Path("D:/a/") #use r if on windows.

files = [f for f in p.glob('*test*.txt')]

for file in files:
    repl = re.sub('test','c',file.stem) 
    df = pd.read_csv(file...)
    df['your_col'] = pd.to_numeric(df['your_col'].str.replace('\w{3}:',''),errors='coerce')
    target_path = file.parent.joinpath(repl)
    df.to_csv(f"{repl}.csv")
```

Comment: @Datanovice-Thank you for helping me. I ran your code, but it occurs the error. The error is as follows :
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2645             try:
-> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:

Comment: pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'abc'

Comment: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-3f73f80d64b6> in <module>
     10     repl = re.sub('test','c',file.stem)
     11     df = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=[1,2,3], dtype=str, delim_whitespace=True)
---> 12     df['abc'] = pd.to_numeric(df['abc'].str.replace('\w{3}:',''),errors='coerce')
     13     target_path = file.parent.joinpath(repl)
     14     df.to_csv(f"{repl}.csv")

Comment: ~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2798             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2799                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2800             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2801             if is_integer(indexer):
   2802                 indexer = [indexer]

Comment: ~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:
-> 2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2649         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2650         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

Comment: pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'abc'

Comment: @Datanovice-Do you know how to change 'abc:,' using re.sub(). 'abc:' is [0:1] in matrix. Also, Do you know how to delete [0:1] in matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the re-naming: have a look at the [pathlib module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#basic-use), using this it's very easy to work with files.

An example to collect and rename the files:

```
from pathlib import Path

path2folder = Path('.')                      # define the folder containing the files
paths2txt_files = path2folder.glob('*.txt')  # collect all *.txt-files

for path in paths2txt_files:
  old_name = path.name                      # extract only the filename from the path
  new_name = old_name.replace('test', 'c')  # replace string in filename
  new_path = path.with_name(new_name)       # create a path with the new filename
  new_path = new_path.with_suffix('.csv')   # change the file ending, replace .txt with .csv
  path.rename(new_path)                     # rename the file
```

And here is a simple example for removing the first n lines from a file:

```
from pathlib import Path

# define the folder containing the raw files
path2folder = Path('.')                

# define and create a new folder for the processed 
# files, you don't want to overwrite your original data
path2processed = path2folder / 'processed'
if not path2processed.exists():
  path2processed.mkdir()

paths2csv_files = list(path2folder.glob('*.csv'))  # collect all *.csv-files
nr_lines_to_skip = 4                               # define the lines to skip

for file in paths2csv_files:

  # read the file, line by line
  with open(file, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

  # remove the first lines
  filtered_lines = lines[nr_lines_to_skip :]

  # write the filtered lines to a new file
  new_file = path2processed / file
  with open(new_file, 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(filtered_lines)
```

Comment: @tom-Thank you for helping me. Do you know how to remove 'abc:,' row?

Comment: @platanus ok, just updated my answer, have a look :-)